# How do I get more than 5 videos from a playlist with Youtubes API

Tags: javascript, youtube

This gets only 5 videos from my playlist, when there is over 100.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={MY_PLAYLIST}&key={MY_KEY}',
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
   }
});
```

I can't figure out what to add to the url to get more than 5 videos.

Answer (score 1):

Using the available "try-it" functionality in the [official documentation *(in spanish)*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)<sup>1</sup>, I built this URL request for set the `maxResults` parameter with the quantity of videos from a given playlist to retrieve.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?maxResults=10&part=contentDetails&playlistId=PLZCHH_4VqpRhwzNjMBHJOcfdMhYZzC0K2&key=YOU_API_KEY
```

In this case, I'm using the playlist called [Microsoft HoloLens: Developer Information](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZCHH_4VqpRhwzNjMBHJOcfdMhYZzC0K2) - this playlist contains 31 videos - *(and in the URL request, the `maxResults` parameter is set to **10**)*.

The following information was taken from the YouTube Data API - official documentation:

- **key**: your API key.
- **part**: The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more search resource properties that the API response will include. For this case, I added *`contentDetails`*.
- **playlistId**: the Id of the playlist to use in the request.
- **maxResults**: specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5.

---

<sup>1</sup> *(Link to the official documentation in english can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=en))*.